# Branch.io Deferred deeplinking in cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova, branch.io

Generally, when user scans the QR code or sends the designated SMS in the hotel, the user should:
- if the app is not already installed, it should be installed with the current location's content
- if the app is installed already (i.e. from a visit to another hotel using our system), it should check and see if the app needs updating, update if needed, and then load the content for the current hotel location.

But I got deeplinking only how to write the cordova(.js) code in js file. 
i followd the link:https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/sdk-integration-guide/guide/cordova/

but there is no infromation for how to redirecting to specific hotel.
So please help me from this problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i had read about this in a article that you will have to re-direct them according to your ui-router. By default it will always open your index file. but if you want the deeplink to work on specific pages you have configure them in your ui-router.This article explains it [link](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/ionic)

Answer (score 0):

Alex from Branch.io here: what you're trying to do is Deep Link Routing. This is what allows you to embed information about the hotel into the QR code/SMS link, and then after the app is open you can make sure the user sees the correct content. We have a guide about it [here](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/deep-link-routing/advanced/cordova/#building-a-custom-deep-link-routing-method)

Comment: I followed your link even though i didn't redirect to specific page.every time its open the first page In java script file it doesn't call the DeepLinkHandler().please guide me for creating dynamic links

Comment: The best option is to contact our [Integration Engineering team](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new). They'll be able to help out with getting things implemented!

Comment: @AlexBauer Within my app I have a QR scanner and it's generated with the **.app.link branch link. Im trying to open it with the in-app browser hoping that it will relaunch the app and get the data from the link. But doesn't work as expected. Can you advise me on how I can Read the QR and extract data from that branch link? THanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Branch deffered deeplink is worked fine for me by following this link:https://github.com/BranchMetrics/cordova-ionic-phonegap-branch-deep-linking/blob/master/testbed/www/js/index.js

Comment: dead link, :-( :-(